# matplotlib 5 square subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying with little success to graph 5 sets of data side by side using matplotlib. Whether I use subplot2grid or simply subplot, I can't seem to avoid getting skinny graphs. I would like 5 graphs side by side with 1:1 height:width. I'm using the range() just for simplicity (I can successfully graph my data in single plots)

```
x = range(10)
y = range(10,20,1)
a1 = plt.subplot(151)
a1.plot(y,x)

a2 = plt.subplot(152)
a2.plot(x,y)

a3 = plt.subplot(153)
a3.plot(x,y)

a4 = plt.subplot(154)
a4.plot(x,y)

a5 = plt.subplot(155)
a5.plot(x,y)
```

I do plan on saving it to a pdf using

```
with PdfPages('fname.pdf') as pdf:
    plt.close('all')
    fig = plt.figure()

    script_for_plots_like_above()

    plt.tight_layout()
    pdf.savefig(fig)
```

But for now I just want the side by side figures. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. Making the plots square.
2. Making the canvas a good size for your plots.

To make the plots square, you can use `ax.set_aspect('equal')` on each axes. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
x = range(10)
y = range(10,20,1)

a1 = plt.subplot(151)
a1.plot(y,x)
a1.set_aspect('equal')

a2 = plt.subplot(152)
a2.plot(x,y)
a2.set_aspect('equal')

a3 = plt.subplot(153)
a3.plot(x,y)
a3.set_aspect('equal')

a4 = plt.subplot(154)
a4.plot(x,y)
a4.set_aspect('equal')

a5 = plt.subplot(155)
a5.plot(x,y)
a5.set_aspect('equal')

plt.savefig('plots-with-aspect.png')
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

Notice that the plots are now square, but they're in the middle of a lot of empty space. You want to adjust the size of the plot to fit the axes, using `figsize=(x,y)`, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(5*5, 5))
x = range(10)
y = range(10,20,1)

a1 = plt.subplot(151)
a1.plot(y,x)
a1.set_aspect('equal')

a2 = plt.subplot(152)
a2.plot(x,y)
a2.set_aspect('equal')

a3 = plt.subplot(153)
a3.plot(x,y)
a3.set_aspect('equal')

a4 = plt.subplot(154)
a4.plot(x,y)
a4.set_aspect('equal')

a5 = plt.subplot(155)
a5.plot(x,y)
a5.set_aspect('equal')

plt.savefig('plots-with-aspect-size.png')
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

Note that the size is calculated relative to the number of axes in each axis.

To further adjust the plot to fit the image, you can for example set a tight layout when saving, e.g.

```
plt.savefig('plots-with-aspect-size-tight.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Produces:

[image]